gazebo showing blackscreen after launching then not responding
I am new to both Linux and ROS and sequentially Gazebo. I installed Linux Mint then installed ROS Jazzy then based on that Gazebo Harmonic.
I am launching the simulator with
source /opt/ros/jazzy/setup.bash
gz sim

but after loading it shows me the inital screen to choose example templates like NAO Joint control or new blank file etc. Whatever I click it goes on black screen then goes not responding.
I am using intel i5 card, with Nvidia 1050ti GPU. and my current selected driver is the latest nvidia driver 550
After running glxinfo
This is what I get https://pastebin.com/a6fG1Fdr
I tried my way but I dont understand enough of anything to debug myself.. please help.

I believe the issue is that multicast is not enabled.
See: https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#enable-multicast
Basically you have to update your firewall configuration to allow multicast using ufw.
sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 224.0.0.0/4
sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 224.0.0.0/4

Also, the first time running Gazebo may take some time because it may download models. Try also enabling verbose logging initially, as it can also help point as to what the issue is.
